# Is the reading のぼる climb or あがる increase

Tags: readings

In today's *Yomiuri*, the following sentence appeared:

空自【くうじ】が保有【ほゆう】しているのは計【けい】３１３機【き】（２０２１年【ねん】３月末【がつまつ】現在【げんざい】）だが、中国軍【ちゅうごくぐん】は計【けい】１１４６機【き】に上【のぼ】る

*The Air Self-Defense Force has a total of 313 aircraft (as of the end of March 2021), while the Chinese military has a total of 1,146.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/column/civil02/20220223-OYT8T50001/2/

Is the reading of the last verb

上る【のぼる】 climb

or

上る【あがる】 increase

(I hope I got the readings of the other parts correct and apologize if I did not)

Comment: It seems to be pronounced as のぼる according to https://youglish.com/pronounce/%E3%81%AB%E4%B8%8A%E3%82%8B/japanese?

Comment: あがる is normally written as 上がる.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy Yang! I knew about youglish for English, but it never occurred to me to use it for Japanese! :D Your link made me very happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is read [のぼる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%8A%E3%82%8B/#jn-172351), which has several meanings. One of them is *(an amount) reaches X*:

> ７ 数量が、無視できない相当の程度に達する。「死傷者が数百人に―・る」
>
> [補説]1㋐は「登る」、3・5は「昇る」、その他は「上る」と書くことが多い。

The reading is decided only on meaning.